# trying to save a terminal command in mac

Tags: macos, terminal

Trying to save this command as a file:

```
node chrome-devtools-autosave-server/index.js
```

I get an error message when trying to open it saying "the file "chrome-save.command" could not be opened because you do not have appropriate access privileges.

New to this! Very! Thanks very much! :D

Comment: Did you make the file executeable? `chmod +x chrome-save.command`

Comment: @prodigitalson Where do I put that? Sorry new to this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run in Terminal

```
chmod +x path/to/chrome-save.command
```

Anyway, the latest version of [chrome-devtools-autosave-server](https://github.com/NV/chrome-devtools-autosave-server/) comes with "autosave" executable. You just type "autosave" in terminal to run it.